# Convert the following hexadecimal representation of 2’s complement binary numbers to decimal numbers.

Tags: binary

I need to convert the following hexadecimal representation of 2’s complement binary numbers to decimal numbers I am unsure if I am doing it correctly or am I missing a step?

a.  xF0

b.  x7FF

c.  x16

d.  x8000

---

My Attempt at first converting it to a Decimal then Binary:

a.  xF0 = 240 = 11110000

b.  x7FF = 2047 = 11111111111

c.  x16 = 22 = 10110

d.  x8000 = 32768 = 1000000000000000

Comment: Are you certain that none of these "2's complement binary numbers" are supposed to be negative decimal numbers?

Comment: @Jonny How can you tell?

Comment: "Two's complement" doesn't mean anything until you're told that the number is supposed to be stored in a location that holds $n$ binary bits. How many binary bits are you supposed to assume?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable presumption to me. Or 16 bits, or 32 bits...

Comment: Only two of your numbers will even fit in $8$ bits. The other two require at least $11$ bits and $16$ bits.

Comment: Usually, there is a size given. For example your first number xF0, if it is an 8 bit 2s compliment then its decimal representation is actually $2^{8-1}- 240$ or -112. If it is a larger bit number, then your positive results are all correct.

Comment: Ok but is my conversion to Decimal numbers at least correct?

Comment: Using the programable calulator on Windows my above answers seem correct though? ie F0 is 240 in decimal and 11110000 in binary...

Comment: Calculators for binary-decimal conversions usually only deal with non-negative numbers. They won't show you the two's complement value, because they have no way of knowing how many bits the number is really supposed to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, but you're missing a step. You know how to obtain the unsigned value, but you're missing the next step that gives you the signed value.

Let's call $c$ the unsigned value, $\mathcal{L}$ the bit length and $n$ the signed value. Like Tony, I'm going to assume that a. and c. are supposed to be 8-bit, and b. and d. are supposed to be 16-bit. This means then that $\mathcal{L} = 8$ or 16. To get $n$ from $c$, you `XOR` $c$ with $2^\mathcal{L} - 1$, add 1 and then multiply by $-1$. Or much easier, $n = c - 2^\mathcal{L}$.

a. `xF0` as an unsigned byte would indeed mean 240. But what does it mean as a signed byte? It's a very well chosen example for educational purposes, since, as Dave explains, each hexadecimal digit corresponds to four bits, and since `xF` is four bits on and `x0` is four bits off, they "toggle" to each other (which is the same as what Tony called `XOR`ing with `xFF`), that is, `xF0` toggles to `x0F`, and that means 15 in decimal. Now you add `x01` to obtain `x10`, which is 16. So `xF0` as a signed byte means $-16$. You can doublecheck by seeing that $240 - 256 = -16$.

b. If this is supposed to be a 16-bit word, e.g., `x07FF`, the sign bit is 0, so you're done. It's 2047, just like you said.

c. Whether this is a byte or a word, the sign bit is also 0 and you're done.

d. This one can be very confusing if you're the slightest bit dyslexic, so you have to take it step-by-step. Do `x8000 XOR xFFFF` to obtain `x7FFF`, which means 32767. Add 1 to obtain 32768 and multiply by $-1$ to obtain $-32768$. Verify this with the subtraction method: we have $c = 32768$ and $\mathcal{L} = 16$, so then $2^\mathcal{L} = 65536$, and therefore $n = 32768 - 65536 = -32768$.

Did d. feel circuitous and confusing, and make you question why we use two's complement at all and not some simpler method (such as just a sign bit without two's complement)? The answer is that we don't use two's complement, computers do. And for computers, two's complement solves two important problems: it ensures a unique representation for 0 and preserves the least significant bit as the parity bit. But I might be stepping on your teacher's toes with that, so I won't say anything more about it.

Lastly, I promised I would mention Programmer Mode in the Windows Calculator. I'm using Windows 8. In the Desktop app, I press Windows-R and type `calc` to invoke the Windows 8.0 Calculator 6.2. Then I switch from Scientific Mode to Programmer Mode by pressing Alt-3. (Or you can use the menu: View -> Programmer). You can set it to byte, word, double word ($\mathcal{L} = 32$) or quadruple word ($\mathcal{L} = 64$). Notice also the Xor button. To work through exercises a. through d. with the Xor button, use either the Dword or Qword setting. And then just to be extra sure, set it to Word and compute $-2 * 2$. Then repeatedly press Enter until you reach $-32768$. Take a look just a little bit below where it says $-32768$. Look familiar? And lastly, set it to Byte and compute $0 - 16$.

By the way, the Mac OS X Calculator also has Programmer Mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you put "two's complement" in the search box, you can find a great many
questions and answers describing two's complement.

But I'll try to give a quick overview of hexadecimal vs. binary notation and two's complement.

**Hexadecimal vs. binary**

Converting between hexadecimal and binary numbers is actually extremely easy. You can do it by hand without any intermediate calculations. The key fact to remember is that one hexadecimal digit equals *exactly* four binary digits.

For example, $\mathrm d_{16} = 1101_2.$
(Subscript $16$ indicates a hexadecimal number, subscript $2$ indicates binary.)
Similarly, $8_{16} = 1000_2,$  $7_{16} = 0111_2,$ and $1_{16} = 0001_2.$
(Notice that for the purpose of this conversion algorithm we *always* write four
digits of the binary number.)

For multiple hexadecimal digits, we can convert to binary just by concatenating the four-bit equivalents:
$$178\mathrm d_{16} = 0001\ 0111\ 1000\ 1101_2.$$
I've shown the binary number with spaces between the four-bit groups. Of course when
writing the number normally you would probably close up those spaces, and you might
omit the leading zeros. Just remember you can only omit leading zeros *after* concatenating
the four-bit groups together.

Converting from binary to hexadecimal is just the reverse process. Group the bits of your
binary number in four-bit groups, starting from the rightmost bit. Each group of four bits is replaced by the equal hexadecimal bit. So if we are given the binary number
$1011110001101_2,$ we can write
$$1\ 0111\ 1000\ 1101_2 = 178\mathrm d_{16}.$$

**Two's complement**

Mathematically, you can speak of a generic "unsigned" binary representation of non-negative numbers; you can use as many bits as you need to represent any non-negative integer you want. But there is no generic *two's complement* representation.
There are only $n$-bit two's complement representations.

In the vast majority of current-day applications, $n$ is $16$ or $32,$ but it is sometimes $64$ or even $8.$ But $n$ does not have to be a power of $2,$ in principle, and in the past there were computers that stored integers using $n$ bits where $n$ was not a power of $2.$

The least number that can be written in an $n$-bit two's complement representation
is $-2^{n-1}.$ The greatest is $2^{n-1} - 1.$ It is also possible to write any integer
between those two values.

To write a non-negative integer in $n$-bit two's complement notation, provided the number
is no larger than $2^{n-1} - 1,$ you simply write the number in binary and "pad" it on the left with $0$ digits until there are $n$ digits altogether.
The number you start with cannot have more than $n - 1$ bits before the "padding,"
so the leftmost bit will always be $0.$

To write a negative integer, provided that it is no less than $-2^{n-1},$
the procedure that is usually recommended is to write the absolute value of the number as an ordinary binary number, "flip" all the bits (every $0$ becomes a $1$ and every $1$ becomes a $0$), and then add one.  The leftmost bit of the result will always be $1.$

Mathematically, the $n$-bit two's complement representation of an integer $x$ for 
$-2^{n-1} \le x < 0$ is the same as the ordinary (unsigned) binary number
equal to $2^n + x.$  In other words, compute $2^n + x$ using ordinary (unlimited bits)
binary notation, and after you have written the result, 
declare it to be $n$-bit two's complement.
This is an alternative to the "flip bits and add one"
algorithm, and always produces the same result provided that your number is
within the range that can be represented.
It is clear that when the result is viewed as an unsigned number,
is in the range $2^{n-1}$ to $2^n - 1,$ therefore it is always an $n$-bit
binary number whose leftmost bit is $1.$

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I'm going to assume that a. and c. are supposed to be 8-bit, and b. and d. are supposed to be 16-bit.

There are just two steps. First, you `XOR` the number with `FF` or `FFFF`, and then you add 1. That's it.

So, with `F0`,  you `XOR` with `FF` to get 15, and then you add 1 to get 16, so `F0` means $-16$.

If you're still unsure, you can check with either your computer's calculator in Programmer Mode, or with an online calculator like http://planetcalc.com/747/ I'm sure there's a way to use WolframAlpha for this purpose, too.

Comment: My queston did not indicate any bit value? Can you you convert without defining the bit value?

Comment: Not unless you've amended your question to indicate a bit value (you can do that, by the way). And yeah, I can convert without defining the bit value: I assume what it is. My calculation could of course then turn out to be wrong.

Comment: Using the programable calulator on Windows my above answers seem correct though? ie F0 is 240 in decimal and 11110000 in binary...

Comment: Actually, Programmer Mode can do you one better, as I'll explain in my answer.